# "expected ")" at line 17 got "="" and "expected identifier when parsing expression got "}" " all at line 47

Tags: roblox

i have problems with the line with the properties variable. it says at line 17 there was a ( in there but when i checked there wasnt. then at the end of the variable i put a } to close the table but it says it expected a identifier when parsing the expression (its a statement).
take a look at the entire script. there is no ( at line 17

`

```
local gui=script.Parent
local screengui=gui.Parent
local energy=100
local maxenergy=100
local shifton=0

local player=game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char=player.Character
local human=char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local userinput=game:GetService("UserInputService")

local function keystart(input,gameproccess)
    if not gameproccess then
        if input.UserInputType==Enum.UserInputType.Keyboard then
            local keycode=input.KeyCode
            if keycode==Enum.KeyCode.RightShift then 
        shifton=1
            end
        end
    end
end
local function keyend(input,gameproccess)
    if not gameproccess then
        if input.UserInputType==Enum.UserInputType.Keyboard then
            local keycode=input.KeyCode
            if keycode==Enum.KeyCode.RightShift then
                    shifton=0
            end
        end
    end
end
userinput.InputBegan:Connect(keystart)
userinput.InputEnded:Connect(keyend)
while true do
    if shifton==1 and energy>0 then
        human.WalkSpeed=16
        energy-=0.1
    else
        human.WalkSpeed=10
        shifton=0
        if energy<maxenergy-1 then
            energy+=0.1
        else
            energy=100
        end
    end
    local property={gui.Size.X=UDim2.new(guienergy,0,0.05,0).X}
    local part=script.Parent
local TweenInf=TweenInfo.new(1,Enum.EasingStyle.Exponential,Enum.EasingDirection.InOut,-1,true,0)
    guienergy=((energy/maxenergy)*0.9)
    tween=game.TweenService:Create(part,TweenInf,property)
    
    tween:Play()    

    wait(0)
end
```

`

Comment: It is here, there are not matching parentheses....`guienergy=((energy/maxenergy)*0.9)`

Comment: Can you please give us the full error n the output. I find it hard to decifer what your trying to explain what the error is.